# Laravel automatically delete blog post when it pass its expiry date

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel app I upload blog posts. All posts have a unix expiry date eg `1492425121` What I want to do is to automatically delete all posts that pass its expiry date.

Right now I am running a cron job each night that checks for old posts then deletes them, but is there any other way I can delete them right away?

Comment: Are you running the crons through Laravel task scheduler?

Comment: @RossWilson I setup a artisan command

Answer (score 3):

You can use [scheduled task](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) for that. In this task, do something like this:

```
Post::where('expiration_date', '<', Carbon::now())->delete();
```

Comment: I am using a artisan command like this example:
https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge/episodes/6

But isnt Laravels scheduled task almost the same thing? It works like a cron job and fires every X hour? I want to delete a old post once it gets old and not wait for a cron job to do it

Comment: @Kiow scheduler uses cron and it will run your command with some interval (every minute, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Then instead of running your command on night make it schedule that it run every minute and check whether post exp time and server time equals then delete it ,

schedule your command like this way:
  $schedule->command('MakeXpZero')->everyMinute();